# Share a folder on server with a workstation

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, file-sharing

Suppose we have a Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter (MS Virtual Machine), than we access remotely via RDP to edit some files in a folder (say, "D:\MyProject").

The problem is that we have a team of 3 people, but an MS server can have max 2 connections simultaneously. So, if the 3rd person connects, it should eject another one...

Usually we don't modify the other files on the server, but the files from that "MyProject" folder.

Is there a way to share that server folder, files to be accessible in edition mode from the work station?
However, we don't want the files be accessible to everybody, but to the 3 people (identified with AD or something similar?)

Comment: `The problem is that we have a team of 3 people, but an MS server can have max 2 connections simultaneously.` - You're clearly violating the EULA. The two RDP connections you speak of are for administration of the server, not for running applications and workloads. If you need to run applications and workloads via RDP then you need to install the RDSH role, the RDSH License Server role, and you need to purchase the appropriate number and type of RDS CAL's.

Comment: thanks, I don't need to launch any application, just to be able to edit some text files in the same time.

Comment: That is a violation of the EULA. The two RDP sessions are for administration of the server. Any other use is a violation.

Comment: thanks, however, the question wasn't about EULA, and we may be tree administrators willing to administrate the server on the same time.

Comment: No, the question was about using the server in a way that violates the EULA. I was simply pointing that out.

Comment: the question wasn't about how to connect 3 via RDP, but how to avoid it, by sharing a folder so there would be no need to connect to the server via RDP, and not violate anything

Answer (score 0):

You can share the folder and give read/write access to the users you want.  Then all three can access the folder using \\serverip\sharedfoldername format.  Are you having trouble with approach ? or you need further details as to how to share the folder?

Comment: the server is on the MS cloud, but the workstation is an enterprise network, so, there are two different networks... will it work?

Comment: It depends.  If you have VPN connectivity between MS Cloud and your enterprise network, it can work as long as you enable file sharing in Windows Firewall.

Comment: i said "no, make the network private", and tried to access via \\serverIP\MyFolder, does not work

Comment: when i try to share it says "Do you want to turn on network discovery and file sharing for all public networks?" No, make the network to a private network, or turn on ?

Comment: to Private network

Comment: didn't work. the \\serverIP does not work neither in private nor public, How to enable the firewall? from the server or the client side?

Comment: on the server you need to enable file sharing in windows firewall